# I am trying to add a shadow to view but it doesn't work. How to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I have declared UIView, and added border with clear color and shadow with black color.
However it doesn't seem like it is working because I am not getting any shadow.

changing `view.clipsToBounds = true` to `view.clipsToBounds = false`
and
`view.layer.masksToBounds = true` to `view.layer.masksToBounds = false`
does not resolve the issue

```
    var backView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.layer.borderColor  =  UIColor.clear.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        view.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
        view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).cgPath
        return view
    }()
```

Comment: you will not get that with  `view.clipsToBounds = true ,  view.layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: set `view.layer.masksToBounds = false`

Comment: setting `view.clipsToBounds = false ,  view.layer.masksToBounds = false` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you set the frame before setting shadows. As your `view.bounds` is `(0,0,0,0)`

```
UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).cgPath
```

or update the path after setting a new frame.
Here the results:

[image]

Comment: Agree, All `bounds`/`frame` related stuff should be done after view is layouted.